# A multiple choice test consists of seven questions, each of which has five choices. Each question has exactly one correct answer.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, combinations, binomial-distribution

What is the probability of getting five or fewer questions correct if guessing on all answers? (Round your answer to four decimal places.)

I have attempted to use the formula for binomial distribution and inputted $C(7,5)(1/5)^5(4/5)^2$, but I am provided $336/78125$ or $.0043$, and this is incorrect. I have also tried using simple logic that if $5$ are correct or fewer then at least $2$ have to be incorrect, so $4/5 \cdot 4/5 = 16/25 - 1 = 9/25 = .36$, and that is incorrect. Any guidance for a different approach is needed. I know it's simple but I feel like I've hit a wall.

Comment: Your posting is hard to read.  Please convert the Math via [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), perhaps using `$\binom{n}{k}$` to represent $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k![(n-k)!]}.$$  Also, please edit your posting to judiciously insert paragraph breaks and line breaks.  The line breaks may be done via `<br>`.

Comment: The binomial distribution formula you used is for *exactly* 5 correct, not 5 or fewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of getting all 7 answers correct is $(\frac{1}{5})^7$.

The probability of getting only 1 answer wrong would be $7 \cdot (\frac{1}{5})^6 \frac{4}{5}$

Therefore the probability of getting 5 answers or less correct would be $1- (\frac{1}{5})^7 - 7 \cdot (\frac{1}{5})^6 \frac{4}{5}$